# Any? to Dictionary Cast and retrieving value

Tags: swift

a function test receiving Any? optional object, once we are sure it's not nil, how can we get hold of underlying dictionary value.

Error: Any doesn't have a member named subscript. Casting to a Dictionary didn't help either. `println(paramValue as Dictionary)` `Any is not convertible to Dictionary<Key, Value>`

```
func test(params: Any?) {

    if let paramValue = params {
        println(paramValue)
        //println(paramValue["value"])
    }

}

test(["value": 10])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`println(paramValue as Dictionary)` won't work because dictionary is type-safe.

You could use:

```
println(paramValue as [String : Int])
```

if those will always be the right types.

If they might change, use optional casting (`as?` instead of `as`).